# Where is Laravel Slack Webhook URL defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Continuing with my Laravel 5.5 project, I'm confused as to where you define the slack webhook URL in the Laravel app.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#routing-slack-notifications shows defining a `routeNotificationForSlack` method on the `User` (or whatever `notifiable` model) that returns `$this->slack_webhook_url`-- but that var is never populated:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function routeNotificationForSlack()
    {
        return $this->slack_webhook_url;
    }
```

Should the `slack_webhook_url` be hardcoded in this model, or is it passed in when you instantiate the notification?

Comment: Use this package https://github.com/maknz/slack-laravel for more neat configuration where you can specify more than one webhook or put the hardcoded webhook URL

Comment: This should help https://medium.com/@olayinka.omole/sending-slack-notifications-from-your-laravel-app-1bdb6e4e4127

Comment: @Suraj-- thanks-- however, that `maknz` package is no longer being maintained.

Comment: Oh, but that can give you an idea to create your own custom configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's up to you how to implement `routeNotificationForSlack()`, Laravel will only call it and use the return value to determine what url to ping.

If all your users share same webhook endpoint, you can store it in `.env`, if they are different for each user, return a database column like the example. If it depends on group/privilege, you should implement it accordingly